# Set datacontext dependency property

Tags: wpf, binding

I am trying to set datacontext of a control using the following code:

```
public object GlobalContext
{
    set { this.SetValue(global.DataContext as DependencyProperty , value);  }
}
```

Where global is a control, in this case a stackpanel.

When I mouse over `global.DataContext` it says its a dependency property so I figured it should work, but I get the following error:

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'GlobalContext' property of type 'ResourceModuleAccessView'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Any way I can make this work?

Edit 1: 
In the user control I have:

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="global" Orientation="Horizontal">
```

and in the places where I am trying to reuse the control:

```
    <my:ResourceModuleAccessView  

        ControlName="Usage Monitoring"
        GlobalContext="{Binding Path=moduleAccess.GlobalAccess[ResourceModule.UsageMonitoring]}"          
          GroupContext="{Binding Path=moduleAccess.Items[ResourceModule.UsageMonitoring]}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GlobalContext class must inheirit from DependencyObject if you are going to use it as a binding target or use the SetValue method. Also, you should pass the static DataContext**Property** from `FrameworkElement` to setValue, thats the actual dependecy property object, you're passing the datacontext object twice. In other words the call should be

```
SetValue(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty,value);
```

i suspect there is something else wrong than this code though, can you post your xaml?

-edit-

Thanks for adding the code, since you're binding **To** your class (you class is a [binding target as opposed to a binding source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#basic_data_binding_concepts)), you must make it a DependecyObject and make your `GlobalContext` a DependecyProperty.

Also note that when the binding system sets a dependecy property, it doesnt use the regular clr property, it uses the DependencyProperty object directly. This means that if you want to register a call back for when the property is changed, you must do that in the call to [Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502.aspx) when you create the DependecyProperty

Comment: thanks that fixed the issue although I still have some inconsistencies with the data binding. 

I actually had dependency properties declared but they were commented out, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

The DataContext property, which is defined on `FrameworkElement` is a dependency property, i.e. it is a property that is 'backed' by the WPF dependency property framework. However the type of this property is `object`. The fact that it is a dependency property tells you how it is stored, not the type of the data stored within it.